# Can I pass an argument to msc through xbuild on the command line?

Tags: xbuild

Is there a way with xbuild, either through the command line or within a build script, to pass additional arguments through to the compiler? Specifically, I want to pass in `--mcs-debug 1` to get a stack trace for [an internal compiler error](https://travis-ci.org/libgit2/libgit2sharp/builds/10652573).

I was able to work around it by updating `%MONO%\bin\gmcs`, but I expect there's a better way.

Comment: Other than extending your own csc, or using an exec task, i don't know of any. https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Microsoft.Build.Tasks/Microsoft.Build.Tasks/Csc.cs