# How to compile a solution that uses unsafe code?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, unsafe, xbuild

How to compile a `Visual Studio 2010` solution using `xbuild` that uses `unsafe` code?

Currently I get this error:

> Implementation/MaximumImageColorClassifier.cs(35,13): error CS0227:
>   Unsafe code requires the `unsafe' command line option to be specified

But running:

> xbuild -unsafe [solution file]

or:

> xbuild /unsafe [solution file]

Gives an error:

> MSBUILD: error MSBUILD0004: Too many project files specified

`xbuild` help shows that that's the proper syntax:

> xbuild /?
>   ...
>   xbuild [options] [project-file]

But there is no `unsafe` option, and no "generic" option to provide some compilation flags.

I saw this question: [Can I pass an argument to msc through xbuild on the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503033/can-i-pass-an-argument-to-msc-through-xbuild-on-the-command-line) but it has no definite answer and maybe there is a specific workaround for unsafe code?

Also, in my case `xbuild` is using `dmcs` compiler.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Eventually, I've found the solution myself. It is to put:

```
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
```

in `csproj` file, under appropriate `PropertyGroup` (related to the configuration `xbuild` is using to build the solution). It is correctly interpreted and `unsafe` code compiles fine.

Comment: where exactly do you add this?

Comment: @SullyPanda76cl You should have a `PropertyGroup` tags for release and debug builds (and possibly some other build configurations you have) in your csproj file. It should go as a child element of each of these.